# Using wildcard in bash-variable for echo and grep

Tags: bash, grep, echo

I am trying to come up with a function that searches a given file for a given pattern. If the pattern is not found it shall be appended to the file.

This works fine for some cases, but when my pattern includes special characters, like wildcards (*) this method fails.

Patterns that work:
`pattern="some normal string"`

Patterns that don't work:
`pattern='#include "/path/to/dir/\*.conf"'`

This is my function:

```sh
check_pattern() {
    if ! grep -q "$1" $2
    then
        echo $1 >> $2
    fi
}
```

I' calling my function like this:
`check_pattern $pattern $target_file`

When escaping the wildcard in my pattern variable to get `grep` running correctly `echo` interprets the `\` as character.

So when I run my script a second time my `grep` does not find the pattern and appends it again.

To put it simple:
Stuff that gets appended:
`#include "/path/to/dir/\*.conf"`

Stuff that i want to have appended:
`#include "/path/to/dir/*.conf"`

Is there some way to get my expected result without storing my `echo`-pattern in a second variable?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us how you use your function `check_pattern`.

Comment: added the part above, calling the function like this: `check_pattern $pattern $target_file`

Comment: There are a few options on grep that might do much of what you want already: `-F` fixed strings will ignore any regex symbols `-c` count - says how many matches were found - you are interested in an answer of 0 `-m` max num matches per file - same idea, buit aborts early `-H` print filename even if there is only 1 file.

Comment: try `echo "$1" >> $2` . Good luck.

Comment: and it's worth double-quoting `$2` everywhere as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I got it now.

Using `grep -F` as pointed out by Gem Taylor in combination with calling my function like this `check_pattern "$pattern" "$target_file"` did the tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
grep -f
```

and

```
check_pattern "$pattern" "$target_file"
```